# Selenium: Unable to locate element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am practicing selenium mouse hover and using the website - http://www.flipkart.com, where I am choosing "Samsung" from the "Electronics" menu. Below is my code but it does not work even though the xpaths are correct.

```
@CacheLookup
@FindBy(xpath="//a[@data-tracking-id='electronics']") WebElement Electronics_Menu;
@CacheLookup
@FindBy(xpath=".//*[@id='menu-electronics-tab-0-content']//a[text()='Samsung']") WebElement Samsung_Mobile_Click;

Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(Electronics_Menu).perform();
act.click(Samsung_Mobile_Click).build().perform();
```

This is the error that I get when I run the code:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='menu-electronics-tab-0-content']//a[text()='Samsung']"}
Command duration or timeout: 27.04 seconds
```

Comment: Try this `XPath`: `//a[@title="Samsung"]`

Comment: Thanks!! it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Samsung xpath with the one given in the below code, it worked for me.

```java
public class FlipK {

  WebDriver driver;

  @CacheLookup
  @FindBy(xpath="//a[@data-tracking-id='electronics']")
  WebElement Electronics_Menu;

  @CacheLookup
  @FindBy(xpath=".//*[@id='container']/div/header/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]/ul/li/ul/li[1]/ul/li[2]/a/span[1]")
  WebElement  Samsung_Mobile_Click;

  @Test 
  public void f() throws InterruptedException { 

    driver = new FirefoxDriver();  
    driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/#");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);

    Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    act.moveToElement(Electronics_Menu).perform();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    Samsung_Mobile_Click.click();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi prashanth, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I've edited your question to use markdown tags to mark out your code; this is important because otherwise it isn't possible to read the code.

Comment: Thank you Vince. I appreciate it!